# Spring boot app works when running in IDE but when deployed as a war file the request fails with 500 error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

Ok I'm feeling kinda dumb over here because I can't figure this out so here goes.

I downloaded the most basic Hello World spring boot web app from Spring Initializer. I can get it to run fine using the internal tomcat. BUT when I package to a .war file and deploy to my local tomcat instance, which mimic's the production environment. The app fails. I've tried configuration changes systematically going through the documentation to insure context is correct and basically anything else that I can find that addresses this issue. So far no dice so I'm reaching out to see if someone here has some insight.

The app should return "TEST CLARIOVISTA" from the URL http://localhost:8084/clariovista/

When I run it out of my IDE (Eclipse) no problems. But when I deploy the .war to my local tomcat instance it throws a 500 error with the message:

> Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

The directory tree is properly set up. I didn't change any directory structure from what was given by the Spring Initializer output. So I'm not sure why there's a problem with the template location. Unless that's a red herring and there's something else going on.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

The basics:
SpringBoot 2.1.6.Release,
JDK 1.8,
Tomcat 8.5.27.

Directory tree pic.

[image: Directory tree pic.]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.inferworks</groupId>
<artifactId>clariovista</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>clariovista</name>
<description>Clario Vista Web</description>
<organization>
    <name>Inferworks</name>
    <url>Inferworks.com</url>
</organization>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8084
```

Comment: add your `application.yml` file in your question...........

Comment: application.yml contains one setting. I changed the port to 8084 as per the stage environment requirement.

server:
  port: 8084

Answer (score 0):

Because `spring-boot-starter-web` includes Tomcat by including `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` by default.
If you want to run your application in other web container, you should exclude Tomcat for Spring MVC as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Appreciate the response but that didn't work. I just added that to the POM and deployed with the same result. Here's the portion modified:

               <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
    <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Comment: Also the following dependency in my original pom should have taken care of that.

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

use jar file easy, command: maven install

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.dh.Application</mainClass>
                <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Tried it but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question description, I hope not required thymeleaf.

2 ways you may proceed.

1. if really don't required then remove thymeleaf templates folder and
   thymeleaf dependency from pom.xml and proceed.
2. You want to continue with thymeleaf, please add below class and proceed to deploy and
   give try.

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

       private static final String HTML_5 = "HTML5";

       @Bean
       public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
           final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
           templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
           return templateEngine;
       }

       @Bean
       public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
           final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
           viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
           viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"*.html,*.xhtml,*.txt"});
           return viewResolver;
       }

       @Bean
       public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
           // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's
           // own resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
           final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
           // templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
           templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/");
           templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
           // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
           templateResolver.setTemplateMode(HTML_5);
           templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
           // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
           // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
           templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
           return templateResolver;
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Seshu, the input is much appreciated. Sadly I do require Thymeleaf. And yes I've tried removing it just to see if I could get rid of the error which didn't work. And I tried, just now, the config you supplied and that didn't work either. I'm going to spend more time today debugging to try to push this issue to a resolution. I'm just stunned that  it's taking this much effort to get a super simple Hello World app to successfully run when deployed as a .war.